# Why does my laptop kill my network even if it's turned off?

Tags: networking, router, laptop, switch

This is a really weird issue.

Here are the players:

- My laptop: a Dell Precision with Pop OS 20.04 (a Ubuntu / Debian spinoff) which I use mainly for development work. It has Docker installed which might be relevant to the networking issue. For my work I sometimes connect to a VPN.
- A very generic TP link gigabit switch with 5 ports (1 for 10/100Mbs it seems)
- The switch is connected to my internet router and to a WiFi extender which is part of a mesh network

Every night at around 7/8 pm the part of my network which is connected to the switch (so also the WiFi from the extender) is just gone.

After looking at the lights on the switch I noticed the one connected to my internet router wasn't blinking anymore, so no data was going through it.

And now the weird part: when I physically unplugged the cable which connects to my laptop, everything returned back to normal, but my laptop was turned off!! The port did have a blinking yellow light, but what could a turned off laptop send / receive? After I plug the cable back in the light turns a non blinking orange.

Some of my ideas point toward either wake on LAN behavior or Docker's networking, but I'm pretty stumped. Why would my network have issues each evening at that time? It feels like maybe something expired, perhaps the DHCP lease?

My subnet is 192.168.2.x if that helps.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Kind regards.

Comment: Network adapters are never off anymore, unless you disconnect all power sources. Intel and others has an OS on the chip that still functions when the pc is turned off.

Comment: 1) Does it still happen if the laptop is still running at 7/8pm?
2) Was the unplugging effect a one-off, or is it repeatable?

Comment: The unplugging is repeatable, like clockwork, the network works again, just did it this evening. I might try leaving the laptop on next time to see if it changes things.

Comment: Okay, I had the same issue tonight, turned on my laptop and everything was peachy immediately. Might it have something to do with a Dell USB-C adapter through which my ethernet cable is connected to my laptop?

Comment: I don't think so. It does have the feel of a hardware-related issue, like inadequate power supply to one of the devices you have hooked, up, but then this 7/8pm switchover blows that out of the window so I really don't have an answer. I can only suggest you try to isolate the problem to one device or another by selectively swapping them out till something changes.

Comment: Today I put the computer in (cold) standby instead of turning it off entirely, no issues. So it may be in the USB-C dongle or the network chip, I always keep things updated so maybe an update will fix it or maybe an update has broken it instead. I'll post more specifics later.

Comment: Does disabling Wake on LAN in laptop Bios and in the OS make a difference?

Comment: I had an an unresolved issue with a cable-provided modem router. My computer was ethernet to the router, and I had the rest of the house on a switch with a wifi receiver also on that switch. The cable modem router combo device would about once per day simply decide stop communicating to anything on the port the switch was attached to. Anything on the switch managed to continue to reach each other. **So it was the upstream device** (and possibly an interaction with a device attached to the switch). My computer never lost connection, so I would only know it happened via complaints.